# Can the Google CSE API provide the item relevance score?

Tags: google-search-api, google-custom-search

I'm using the CSE JSON/XML API to search my custom search engine but the results do not include the actual relevance score for each item. Is this completely unsupported or is there a way to retrieve it? I can almost swear I've seen it in the API before :)

There's a "<RK>" ranking element in the (old?) XML API but it's always set to 10 it seems..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exhaustive list of supported fields in json response is documented here:
https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/reference/cse/list#response

So it seems no, relevance score is not provided.